# Flutter using Provider - context.watch<T>() for specific items in a list and ignores the other items updates

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am a newbie in Flutter and I am trying to build an app using Provider. I will try to provide an oversimplified example here. My app includes a model of a room.

```
class Room {
String roomDisplayName;
String roomIdentifier;
Image image;
List<IDevices> devices = [];

Room(this.roomDisplayName, this.roomIdentifier, this.image, this.devices);
}
```

Rooms have list of devices like a temperature sensor

```
class TempSensor implements IDevices {
late String tempSensorName;
late double temperatureValue;
late double humidityValue;
late int battery;

TempSensor(this.displayName, this.zigbeeFriendlyName);

UpdateTempSensor(double temperature, double humidiy, int battery) {
  this.temperatureValue = temperature;
  this.humidityValue = humidiy;
  this.battery = battery;
}
```

I have a RoomProvider class that implements ChangeNotifier that is responsible for updating devices in `List<Room> rooms`

```
class RoomsRepositoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {

List<Room> get rooms {
//return _rooms;
return _rooms;
}

  UpdateTemperatureSensor(TempSensor tempSensor) {
  TempSensor? foundTempSensor = null;
  _rooms.forEach((room) {
    room.devices.forEach((element) {
      if (element.displayName == tempSensor.displayName) {
        foundTempSensor = element as TempSensor;
      }
    });
  });
  if (foundTempSensor != null) {
    foundTempSensor?.UpdateTempSensor(tempSensor.temperatureValue,
        tempSensor.humidityValue, tempSensor.battery);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I also have a Stateful widget page to show Room information like temperature/humidity value.

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
final Room room;

DetailPage({required this.room});

@override
_DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
context.watch<RoomsRepositoryProvider>().rooms;
return Text ("Temperature is ${widget.room.devices[0].temperatureValue}");
}
```

**Here is question:**

The problem I am facing is that, if I am showing the Living Room in `DetailPage` and the temperature sensor from Bedroom gets updated in the `List<Room> rooms`, the whole `DetailPage` gets rebuild. Since it is not an issue in the flutter and the app works good. I would still like to know how to solve this architecture problem, that the `DetailPage` only gets build for the room updates related to the room being shown?

PS: please ignore any build, indentation or naming convention mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved my problem by creating a separate provider `DevicesProvider` that contains the list of devices modified in the room. I provide the current room by calling the method `SetCurrentRoom(String currentRoomIdentifier)` from the `DetailPage` and the provider does its job whenever the devices list in the current room updates.

```
class DevicesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
String _currentRoomIdentifier = "";

List<IDevices> _listCurrentRoomDevices = [];

List<IDevices> get ListCurrentRoomDevices => _listCurrentRoomDevices;

void SetCurrentRoom(String currentRoomIdentifier) {
  _currentRoomIdentifier = currentRoomIdentifier;
}

UpdateDevicesList(IDevices device) {
    if (serviceLocator<RoomProviderService>()
        .rooms
        .any((room) => room.roomIdentifier == _currentRoomIdentifier)) && 
         IsDeviceUpdateComingFromCurrentRoom(device)
      {
        _listCurrentRoomDevices.clear();
        var devices = serviceLocator<RoomProviderService>()
            .rooms
            .firstWhere(
                (room) => room.roomIdentifier == _currentRoomIdentifier)
            .devices;
        _listCurrentRoomDevices.addAll(devices);
        notifyListeners();
      }
   }

bool IsDeviceUpdateComingFromCurrentRoom(IDevices device) {
  bool isUpdateFromCurrentRoom = false;
  if (device.Name.contains(_currentRoomIdentifier)) {
    isUpdateFromCurrenRoom = true;
  }
  return isUpdateFromCurrentRoom;
  }
}
```

Maybe this can be solved in a different way which is more elegant or efficient, but for now my problem is solved with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

To only rebuild the specific widget, you can wrap that widget inside `Consumer` widget provider by `Provider` in flutter. `Consumer` takes a builder function and will build the widget returned by this builder function only when the data changes.

```
Consumer(
   builder:(context,_,__){
     return Container();
  },
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does this solve the above mentioned problem? I want the whole DetailPage to only update when the update comes from the room the DetailPage is showing?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, you can use a Comsumer widget

```
Consumer<RoomsRepositoryProvider>(
builder:(context,value,child) => Text("Temperature is ${value.room}");
),
```

A StatelessWidget is also sufficient. Don't forget the index by room. It should work like this